# Linux: How to map a blockdevice to a USB-device?

Tags: linux, usb-drive, device

if I plugin a USB memory stick, I see a new folder in /sys/bus/usb/devices ... thus a new USB-device.

Also I see a new folder in /sys/block ... thus a new block-device.

My question is: How can I get a waterproof mapping between those two devices? Means:
If I get a new device in /sys/bus/usb/devices, how can I programatically (f.i. by checking /sys/...) find out which block device is mapped/related to this usb-device and vice-versa?!

Answer (score 6):

The information in `/sys` is organized in multiple ways (by driver, by bus, etc.), and there are many symbolic links to go from one hierarchy to another.

Case in point (example seen on kernel 2.6.26): starting from the block device in `/sys/block/sdc`, the symbolic link `/sys/block/sdc/device` points inside the per-device-type hierarchy. You can see that it's an USB device because the target of the link is something like

```
../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb8/8-2/8-2:1.0/host9/target9:0:0/9:0:0:0
```

Conversely, USB devices are listed in `/sys/bus/usb/devices`, and we can see that `8-2:1.0` is a disk-like device because `/sys/bus/usb/devices/8-2:1.0/driver` links to `usb-storage`. To find out what the associated block device is, it seems we need to go down to the directory `/sys/bus/usb/devices/8-2:1.0/host9/target9:0:0/9:0:0:0` which contains a symbolic link `block:sdc` whose target is `/sys/block/sdc`.

**ADDED**: Caution: the exact structure of `/sys` changes from kernel version to kernel version. For example, with kernel 2.6.32, `/sys/block/sdc/device` points directly into the `/dev/bus/scsi` without going through the USB hop.

---

A different approach is to call the `udevadm info` command. `udevadm info -p /sys/block/sdc --query=…` gives information on a device based on its `/sys` entry, while `udevadm info -n sdc --query=…` gives information on the device `/dev/sdc`.

The information includes bus information, for example `udevadm info -p /sys/block/sdc --query=env` shows

```
ID_BUS=usb
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
```

The udev documentation may have more information of interest to you.

---

A final word of caution: there are all kinds of complex cases that may make whatever you do not so waterproof. How will your program deal with a single USB device that is an array of disks that are assigned multiple block devices? Conversely, how will your program deal with a RAID array assembled from multiple devices (perhaps some of them USB and some of them not)? Do you care about other removable media types such as Firewire and e-SATA? etc. You won't be able to predict all corner cases, so make sure to fail gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can follow your sample on a debian machine. But on Ubuntu f.i. /sys/block/sdb contains a "device" link to "../../../7:0:0:0". If I follow the rest of you sample, there is no "block:sdb" symlink. All device paths starting from /sys/block do not show up any hint that this is an USB device :-(

So for debian it might work, but Ubuntu seems to be somehow different. 

The command "udevinfo" is not available with Ubuntu. But there's "udevadm" which seems to be similiar. But parsing a commandline output is maybe not the best?!

Comment: regarding the waterproof issue:

My use cases don't care about raid of different types of devices. It's just about USB flash memory disk. All I need to have is the vendor-id + product-id + serialnumber + the relation to the mountpoint. That's all.

Comment: @Alex: Ok, I had a look and it seems that more more recent kernel versions have a different symlink structure under `/sys`. As far as I can tell `udevinfo` (where it exists) is exactly equivalent to `udevadm info`. It looks like `udevadm info` is the way to go (it gives you vendor and serial number information as well).

Comment: Do you know if there's a way of programtically get this information? via an .so file or system call, rather than executing a command and parsing the output....?!

Comment: @Alex: The information has to come from the kernel somehow. As far as I know (which is not much), most of this information is only available to userland through `/sys`, which we've discovered changes with the kernel version. Udev is maintained in sync with the kernel, and has a mostly-documented API in the form of `udevadm`. `udevadm` works by reading files in `/dev/.udev/db` (created by `udevd` I presume), but these files get reorganized too (e.g. they're not the same on Debian lenny and Ubuntu lucid). I don't know of any other interface. So `udevadm` looks by far the most reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I found out, it's possible to access udev information via "libudev" library. There's also a good sample on the net available: http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/

I was able to modify it to read out all "/dev/sd*" devices and get their Vendor-ID, Product-ID as well as Serial number. I think this solution is kernel/linux distribution independant enough. But I still have to verify this.